# Should I activate "Active State Power Management" as PowerCFG suggests?

Tags: windows-10, power, pci-express, powercfg

After [reading about PowerCFG](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PowerCfgTheHiddenEnergyAndBatteryToolForWindowsYoureNotUsing.aspx) I ran `PowerCfg /energy` on an Admin Powershell which created a html "Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report" that included this bit as and "error":

> **Power Policy:PCI Express ASPM is disabled (Plugged In)**
>   The current power policy for PCI Express Active State Power Management (ASPM) is configured to Off.

What exactly does that mean?
Should I enable it? Where?

Is "Active Sate Power Management" the same as ["Link State Power Management"](https://superuser.com/questions/248974/what-is-link-state-power-management)?
This would mean this is about this setting, correct?

[image: power settings -> PCI Express -> Link State Power management]

Comment: Oh damn, seem I couldn't activate it even if I wanted. Further down the errors list I found this: "Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled - PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to a known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer." - [which itself seems to be a bit of an unkown thing](https://superuser.com/questions/823548/what-is-the-known-hardware-incompatibility-that-disables-pcie-active-state-pow)

Comment: I do not think that Link State Power Management and ASPI are necessarily one and the same thing or only depend on one another -- I have gotten the ASPM warning in my energy report document from `powercfg` but my Link State Power Management is "Maximum Power Savings" for the on-battery state and "Moderate Power Savings" for the plugged-in state.